# Wpf display Collection of data tables

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a question I have a Dictionary that looks like:

```
public Dictionary<string, ValuesDataTable> ValuesDataTable {get; set;} = new Dictionary<string, ValuesDataTable>();
```

Well, it fills like it should so a string and a data table with data, Its OK.

But as this dictionary can has different amount of values(DataTables) I can not assign it to any binding property (or can I?).

So I was wondering is it possible to do display amount of data grids for each Data table in dictionary?

Some sort of foreach element id dictionary

Comment: try ItemsControl

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one way to do that is by using a `DataGrid` inside a `ListView`:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesDataTable}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Value.MyDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Assuming that your Model looks something like that:

```
 public class ValuesDataTable
{
    public DataTable MyDataTable { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to set the `DataContext` and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface:

```
    private Dictionary<string, ValuesDataTable> _valuesDataTable;
    public Dictionary<string, ValuesDataTable> ValuesDataTable
    {
        get { return _valuesDataTable; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _valuesDataTable)) return;
            _valuesDataTable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```